# Why won't Huginn agents act on Webfaction?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-deployment, webfaction

I could spool up a VPS or deploy to a PaaS, but I'm determined to get [Huginn](https://github.com/cantino/huginn) working on my [Webfaction](https://www.webfaction.com/?aid=52204) account because I'm pretty sure it's possible and I just don't get rails deployments.

After hours of hacking away, I ended up with a running app [whose Agents do nothing](https://github.com/cantino/huginn/issues/332). I can't manage to run `foreman start`, the magical command that should solve the problem, so I'm not sure what else to do.

[image: Background jobs that never get executed.]

[image: Choosing 'Run event propagation' confirms a queue of 0 events on 0 agents. 'Working' is always 'no'.]]

### How I got here

I'm used to PHP and these deployments are foreign to me, so I'm certain the problem's between the chair and the keyboard...

1. Created a new Webfaction Application called `huginn` with Rails 4.1.8 (nginx 1.6.2/Passenger 4.0.53/Ruby 2.1.2).
2. Cloned [huginn](https://github.com/cantino/huginn) into its own folder next to the `hello_world` example app that Webfaction initializes. (`~/webapps/huginn/huginn/`)
3. Edited `~/webapps/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` (which came from Webfaction's init script) to point to my cloned `huginn` folder instead of `hello_world`. Changed `GEM_HOME` to `/home/foo/webapps/huginn/huginn/gems` instead of `/home/foo/webapps/huginn/gems`, `root` to `/home/foo/webapps/huginn/huginn/public`, and `rails_env` to `production`.
4. Edited `~/webapps/huginn/bin/start` to adjust paths (see below).
5. Copied and configured Huginn's `.env` properly, pointing to a fresh MySQL database with valid credentials. Added a randomly-generated `APP_SECRET_TOKEN`, set host name and email configuration.
6. Added app bin, path, and gems to PATH using [Webfaction's instructions](http://docs.webfaction.com/software/rails.html).
7. From `~/webapps/huginn/huginn`, ran `gem2.1 install bundle`, `ruby2.1 bin/bundle`, `ruby2.1 bin/bundle exec rake db:migrate`, `ruby2.1 bin/bundle exec rake db:seed` and all goes well; dependencies installed to huginn's directories, database populated, etc.
8. Ran `ruby2.1 bin/bundle exec foreman start` and failed:

> 16:50:03 web.1  | started with pid 7115
>      16:50:03 jobs.1 | started with pid 7116
>      16:50:06 jobs.1 | /home/foo/webapps/huginn/huginn/gems/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/server.rb:22:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/spring/e89e6bd5b6863aeed0fbb5c861b1fc2d.pid (Errno::EACCES)

8. Go back and run `~/webapps/huginn/bin/stop`, `~/webapps/huginn/bin/start`, and the app miraculously starts working in my browser. Except for the Agents, which do nothing on schedule or an attempt to manually run them.

I suspect that I'm missing something when it comes to environment variables and ruby versions. Various ruby versions are available, but `ruby --version` outputs `ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]`. Even I figured out that there are symlinks to different versions, so `ruby2.1 --version` gets me `ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]`. My guess is that the app's using Ruby 1.8.7, and I ran with this trying to [install rvm to select a different ruby version](https://community.webfaction.com/questions/6846/ruby-192)—I didn't make it through `rvm install X.X.X` because I'm not a sudoer and `libyaml-devel` couldn't be installed.

I was briefly excited to learn that I could run `ruby2.1 bin/rails s --port=22766 --environment=production` from the deployed app directory and have the app once again running in the browser—but with the exact same issue of non-responsive agents.

It seems like I'm really close, but that I'm missing something that's consistently leaving Huginn's agents crippled. **What am I missing?**

---

**nginx.conf**

```
env               GEM_HOME=/home/foo/webapps/huginn/huginn/gems;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    access_log  /home/foo/logs/user/access_huginn.log  combined;
    error_log   /home/foo/logs/user/error_huginn.log   crit;

    include         mime.types;
    passenger_root  /home/foo/webapps/huginn/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.53;
    passenger_ruby  /home/foo/webapps/huginn/bin/ruby;
    sendfile        on;

    passenger_max_instances_per_app  1;
    rails_spawn_method               conservative;
    passenger_max_pool_size 2;

    server {
        listen             22766;
        passenger_enabled  on;
        root               /home/foo/webapps/huginn/huginn/public;
        server_name        localhost;
        rails_env          production;
    }
}
```

**~/webapps/huginn/bin/start**

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/foo/bin RUBYLIB=/home/foo/webapps/huginn/huginn/lib:$RUBYLIB TMPDIR=/home/foo/webapps/huginn/tmp PASSENGER_TMPDIR=/home/foo/webapps/huginn/tmp GEM_HOME=/home/foo/webapps/huginn/huginn/gems /home/foo/webapps/huginn/nginx/sbin/nginx -p /home/foo/webapps/huginn/nginx/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to help from John at Webfaction, it boiled down to setting a custom temp directory that could be written to with my account...

```
mkdir -p $HOME/tmp
export TEMP=$HOME/tmp
```

Sure enough, running `ruby2.1 bin/bundle exec foreman start` worked just fine and the Agents sprang to life.

Then I promptly hit the wall of my 512MB memory limit, so it's on to other issues.